# find the longest non decreasing sub sequence

Tags: c, sequence

given a string consists only of 0s and 1s say **10101**
how to find the length of the longest non decreasing sub-sequence??
for example,

> for the string,
>   10101

the longest non decreasing sub sequences are

- 111
- 001
  so you should output 3

> for the string
>   101001

the longest non decreasing sub sequence is

- 0001

so you should output 4
how to find this??

> > how can this be done when we are provided with limits.**sequence between the limit**
> >     for example
> >     101001
> >     limits [3,6]
> >     the longest non decreasing sub sequence is
> >
> > - 001
> >       so you should output 3

**can this be achieved in o(strlen)**

Comment: check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Comment: @HoangHuynh That's `O(N*longN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be achieved in `O(strlen)`?

Yes. Observe that the non-decreasing subsequences would have one of these three forms:

```
0........0 // Only zeros
1........1 // Only ones
0...01...1 // Some zeros followed by some ones
```

The first two forms can be easily checked in `O(1)` by counting all zeros and by counting all ones.

The last one is a bit harder: you need to go through the string keeping the counter of zeros that you've seen so far, along with the length of the longest string of `0...01...1` form that you have discovered so far. At each step where you see `1` in the string, the length of the longest subsequence of the third form is the larger of the number of zeros plus one or the longest `0...01...1` sequence that you've seen so far plus one.

Here is the implementation of the above approach in C:

```
char *str = "10101001";
int longest0=0, longest1=0;
for (char *p = str ; *p ; p++) {
    if (*p == '0') {
        longest0++;
    } else { // *p must be 1
        longest1 = max(longest0, longest1)+1;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", max(longest0, longest1));
```

`max` is defined as follows:

```
#define max( a, b ) ( ((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b) )
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/aQVmGx).

Comment: Basically you just count numbers until you encounter 10 - at this point you compare your current count with highest count and reset counting.

Comment: @aragaer No, not really - you do not reset anything, just update the counts, and move on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : http://ideone.com/aQVmGx see the 4th output. ur program produces wrong results

Comment: for 1110011000001 it produces 5

Comment: @yuv60 My function does not read input, the string is hard-coded at `10101001`, so the answer `5` is correct. [When I modify the program to process `1110011000001`, the output is `8`](http://ideone.com/nrLxgI).

Comment: can you say how to find the length , when we provide a starting and ending index. i.e,, length of sequence from (say) 3 to 8

Comment: @yuv60 That would be no different from the basic string processing: start your `char *p` at `str+offset`, where `offset` is the index of the initial position into the string, and end the run when `p == str+endPos`, where `endPos` is the last position that you would like to process.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: what will you do, if more number of indexes were provided. say find the longest non decreasing sequence of [0,4],[3,9],[2,4],[100,300], .... and so on for 10000 indexes. It will result in TLE

Answer (score 1):

Use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Run through the string from left to right, and keep track of two variables:

- `zero`: length of longest subsequence ending in 0
- `one`: length of longest subsequence ending in 1

If we see a 0, we can append this to any prefix that ends in 0, so we increase `zero`. If we see a 1, we can either append it to the prefix that ends in 0, or in 1, so we set `one` the one which is longest. In C99:

```
int max(int a, int b) {
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

int longest(char *string) {
  int zero = 0;
  int one = 0;
  for (; *string; ++string) {
    switch (*string) {
      case '0':
        ++zero;
        break;
      case '1':
        one = max(zero, one) + 1;
        break;
    }
  }
  return max(zero, one);
}
```

Comment: cool logic.  how can you give the length, when you are provided with a limit, say from index 3 to 8?

Comment: Just run through part of the string. That's left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    count++;
    if (array[i] < prev) {
        if (count > max)
            max = count;
        count = 0;
    }
    prev = array[i];
} while (++i < length);
```

Single pass. Will even work on any numbers, not just 1s and 0s.

For limits - set `i` to starting number, use ending instead of array length.

Comment: It does not appear that this algorithm would work at all. It looks like it would return `2` for the input `"10"`, which would be incorrect (the answer should be `1` in this case). I cannot say for sure, because I do not know what's the initial value of `prev` before the loop.

Comment: It should be something significantly large (`'2'` in case of 0's and 1's) so even the first element would "break the sequence" and we would count from 1.